# Getting textcontent from multiple elements individually using one class name

Tags: javascript, class, event-listener, queryselector

I am developing a calculator as a part of the frontEndMasters course but I cannot get the numbers to work, number seven only works. I would like to know if there is any workaround for this since I thought that I could also write an eventlistener for every button but that would violate DRY.

```js
const screens = document.querySelector(".screen");
const clearing = document.querySelector(".calc-buttonBigC");
const buttons = document.querySelector(".calc-button");

console.log(screens.textContent);

clearing.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    screens.textContent = "";
});

 buttons.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    screens.textContent += buttons.textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class='calc'>
  <section class='screen'>
    
  </section>
<section class='calc-buttons'>
<div class='row'>
  <button class='calc-buttonBigC'>C</button>
  <button class='calc-button-spec'>◄</button>
  <button class='calc-button-spec'>/</button>
</div>
  <div class='row'>
       <button class='calc-button'>7</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>8</butbutton>
      <button class='calc-button'>9</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>x</button>
    </div>
  <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-button'>4</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>5</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>6</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>-</button>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-button'>1</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>2</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>3</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>+</button>
    </div>
  <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-buttonBig'>0</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>=</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have used querySelector and querySelectorAll with the numbers but I only get the number seven to work.

As far as I understand I have to use a for each loop to get all the numbers to work.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `querySelector(".calc-button")`, which looks for the **first** element that matches the supplied selector and that element is the 7 button in your case. If you want to handle all the buttons, you have to set up an event handler for each, use `querySelectorAll()` and then loop over each reference in handler, or (preferably) use "[event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)" to set up one handler for all the buttons and then reference the specific element that triggered the event using the [.target property of the `event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Here's an example to get you back on track:

```js
const screens = document.querySelector(".screen");
const clearing = document.querySelector(".calc-buttonBigC");

// Get a reference to an ancestor element of all the buttons
const calc = document.querySelector(".calc");

clearing.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    screens.textContent = "";
});

// When any of the descendent elements get clicked,
// the event will bubble up to the ancestor and be
// handled here.
calc.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  // The event reference is automatically passed to
  // the handler and you use the .target property of
  // the event to get a reference to the element that
  // originated the event.
    
  // First, determine if the event was triggered by
  // an element you care to handle.
  if(event.target.classList.contains("calc-button")) {
    // Then work with the element
    screens.textContent += event.target.textContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='calc'>
  <section class='screen'></section>
  <section class='calc-buttons'>
  <div class='row'>
    <button class='calc-buttonBigC'>C</button>
    <button class='calc-button-spec'>◄</button>
    <button class='calc-button-spec'>/</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-button'>7</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>8</butbutton>
      <button class='calc-button'>9</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>x</button>
    </div>
  <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-button'>4</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>5</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>6</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>-</button>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-button'>1</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>2</button>
      <button class='calc-button'>3</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>+</button>
    </div>
  <div class='row'>
      <button class='calc-buttonBig'>0</button>
      <button class='calc-button-spec'>=</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```